# Using a function to create multple data frames from a 3D array

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

Thanks for reading. I am new to functions, and want to make my scripts much more readable as they will be shared around and wondered if you could help.

I used to have this peice of scrip to create multiple new dataframes from a 3D data set.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(x$data))
{nam <- paste("timepoint",deparse(i), sep=".")
  assign(nam, 'as.data.frame(print(x$data[,i,])))}
```

Now I want this as a function, not sure on the best return format, but likely a list so that my data is contained within the list as listname$timepoint1

So far I have....

```
funcs <- list()
step2<-function(funcs, x){

for(i in ncol(x$data))
  {
  timepoint <- paste( "timepoint", i, sep = '' )
  funcs[[timepoint]] = assign(timepoint[i],(print(x$data[,i,])))
  } 
return(funcs)

}

tester<-step2(funcs,x)
```

this works, except it only returns the final timepoint. giving at the end....

> summary(tester)
>               Length Class  Mode
>   timepoint79 25600  -none- numeric

Thanks alot

Comment: If you need to create multiple datasets from an array `a1 <- array(1:50, c(5,2, 5));  list2env(setNames(lapply(1:dim(a1)[3], function(i) as.data.frame(a1[,,i])), paste0('timepoint', 1:5)), envir=.GlobalEnv)`